# @2x and @3x in pixels issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I my application I almost don't use fixed size constraints for views, but instead I use percent constraints (so I don't say that view width = 100, I say that view width = 100/320 from the container view). I do it by settings constraints like [this](http://take.ms/UgGpI)

I read this [article](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified)

So as far as I understand now for iPhones I need **@2x images for 750px** screen size and **@3x images for 1242 px** screen size? (before I used @2x for 640px screen width, but for iPhone4,5 it will just scale the image, so it's not so bad)

If it's true, the **ration @3x width to @2x width** will be **1,656** (1242/750) ? If it's true, that's strange, because I thought that the ration should be like 3/2 = 1.5

Comment: it seems strange to be manually scaling your views based on the @#x resolution of the image, you do know that UIImageViews automatically take that into account right? instead you should have different width/height images depending on the phone screen size if you want your picture to be wider/higher on bigger devices, otherwise you are just stretching the image and not getting native resolution. maybe you have your reasons, but just seems odd

Comment: I don't scale for 2x and 3x, and I don't scale only UIImageView, I scale labels, UIViews, buttons and so on.  My main task in the application: ration width of element to width of the screen should always be the same (no matter what device you use).

Comment: oh i see, never mind then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone 6 Plus uses a trick to use 3x assets. They should be 1.5 the size of the 2x artwork as you correctly calculated. What iOS does for the iPhone 6s is create a canvas that has a dpi of 3x. It is then scaled down to fit the screen. Because the pixels are so small it is really hard to see this.

The canvas is 1242×2208, which is then down sampled to 1080×1920. You also need to consider that in "Zoomed" mode the screen can be treated like that of a normal iPhone 6 (i.e. 375x667 points but rendered at 3x). There is a really good guide to all of this here: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: But is it true, that I need @2x icon for 750 px width (not for 640 px width anymore) ?

Comment: What do you mean by icon?

Comment: for example, on design for 5 iphone (640 px width) I have element with width = 100 px. So that mean that for "2x" image I will have 100 * (750 / 640) = 117 px width . And for "3x" I will have 117 * 1.5 = 175 px. Right?

Comment: 2x should be twice as wide as the original, and 3x three times. So your original image is 100px, make the 2x 200px and the 3x 300px. iOS will take care of the rest.

Comment: As I said in the main question, I use percent ration, so in iPhone 6 I will have 117 px width of the element (but on iPhone 5 it will still be 100 px width). So the original (for 375 px) will be 117/2 px. So for @2x I need 117 px ?

Comment: See @Fonix comment above. What you have in mind is nothing that should/can be done via 2x/3x... If you are really into creating content that will exactly fit on the screen, use pre-rendered images of the pre-calculated size one for each device.

Comment: I answered him. If i use pre-rended images I will have too big image for iPhone5 or too small image for iPhone 6. So I use percent ratio. And as far as I understand I will need @2x image for 750 px screen width (not for 640 px screen width as it was before). And that will make the deal. Because as I said: I don't scale only images, I scale UIButtons, UILabels, UIVIews and all other elements. I do it  by settings constraints like this http://take.ms/UgGpI

Comment: you have to manage stuff differently because there is no seperate place for 4 , 5 and 6. all will take @2x expect 6+ images.

Comment: I know and that's why I want @2x image for iphone 6, so for iPhone 4 and 5 it will just scale the image a little. I think it's not so critical?